# Php Print Data by id from MySQl Using pdo and TCPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, tcpdf

---

I want to print a specific invoice by ID
For example, I want to print a customer invoice that is already registered in the database only by clicking on the print button in 
my code

### i dont know how do it so i just add the button i was trying but did't work !

I am new to programming and I do not know if the code has errors but works with me well and shows the invoices of customers but I want to print them

```
<?php
        define("ROW_PER_PAGE",5);
include 'db.php';?>
    <html dir="rtl">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <title>Report List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/fontawesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/materialize.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php   
            $search_keyword = '';
            if(!empty($_POST['search']['keyword'])) {
                $search_keyword = $_POST['search']['keyword'];
            }
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM rp_info WHERE rp_rnumber LIKE :keyword OR rp_name LIKE :keyword OR rp_phonenumber LIKE :keyword ORDER BY rp_id DESC ';
            $per_page_html = '';
            $page = 1;
            $start=0;
            if(!empty($_POST["page"])) {
                $page = $_POST["page"];
                $start=($page-1) * ROW_PER_PAGE;
            }
            $limit=" limit " . $start . "," . ROW_PER_PAGE;
            $pagination_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($sql);
            $pagination_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pagination_statement->execute();
            $row_count = $pagination_statement->rowCount();
            if(!empty($row_count)){
                $per_page_html .= "<div style='text-align:center;margin:20px 0px;'>";
                $page_count=ceil($row_count/ROW_PER_PAGE);
                if($page_count>1) {
                    for($i=1;$i<=$page_count;$i++){
                        if($i==$page){
                            $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page current" />';
                        } else {
                            $per_page_html .= '<input type="submit" name="page" value="' . $i . '" class="btn-page" />';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $per_page_html .= "</div>";
            }
            $query = $sql.$limit;
            $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare($query);
            $pdo_statement->bindValue(':keyword', '%' . $search_keyword . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $pdo_statement->execute();
            $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll(); ?>
            <div class="striped">
                <form name='frmSearch' action='' method='post'>
                    <div style='text-align:center;' '>
                    <div >
                        <label for="search">Search</label><br>
                  <input id="search" class="validate" placeholder="Enter" type="text" name="search[keyword]" value="<?php echo $search_keyword; ?>" maxlength="25" style="margin-right: %50;width: 25%;background: #f5f5f5 url(images/sc.png) no-repeat center left 7px;">
                </div>
        <table class="striped">
          <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>iD</th>
                      <th>Name</th>
                      <th>Unit</th>
                      <th>Rank</th>
                      <th>Print</th>
        </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody id='table-body '>
            <?php
            if(!empty($result)) { 
                foreach($result as $row) {
            ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td><?php echo $row['rp_id'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rp_name'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rp_phonenumber'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rp_rank'];?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['rp_unit'];?></td>
                    <td><input type="submit" name="page" value="PRINT PDF" class="btn-page current" /></td>
                  </tr>
            <?php
                }
            }
            ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php echo $per_page_html; ?>
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: You say you have experience with tcpdf, so where is your attempt to use it?

Comment: I want to print a specific invoice by ID